# A pgfplots bar chart only shows the first x tick

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\pgfplotsset{ every axis/.append style={font=\tiny}}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{test.txt}\mydata;

  \begin{axis}[
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymajorgrids=false,
        no markers,
        ybar, 
     bar shift=0.3pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.05,
        ymin=0,
         major x tick style = transparent,
        xticklabels from table={\mydata}{0},
     xtick=data,
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        ymajorgrids = false,
        bar width=2mm, 
        width=20cm, 
     height=10cm, 
        ylabel={\%},
       /pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd  ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{\addplot table [select row=#1, x expr=#1] {\mydata};}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

test.tx file is

```
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
d, 4
e, 5
f, 6
g, 7
h, 8
i, 9
j, 10
k, 11
```

In the resulting plot all 11 bars are shown but only the x-axis tick "a" is shown, I have done my best to solve the problem but with no avail, any help will be very much welcomed

Answer (score 8):

`xtick=data` only uses the first `\addplot` command for determining the tick positions. You should use `xtick={0,...,10}` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=false]{
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
d, 4
e, 5
f, 6
g, 7
h, 8
i, 9
j, 10
k, 11
}\mydata;

\pgfplotsset{
    select row/.style={
        x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}
    }
}

  \begin{axis}[
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=4pt,
        ymajorgrids=false,
        no markers,
        ybar, 
     bar shift=0.3pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.05,
        ymin=0,
         major x tick style = transparent,
        xticklabels from table={\mydata}{0},
     xtick={0,...,10},
        x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
        ymajorgrids = false,
        bar width=2mm, 
        width=10cm, 
     height=10cm, 
        ylabel={\%},
       /pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd  ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{\addplot table [select row=#1, x expr=#1] {\mydata};}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```